# Granting Azure Application User access to PowerApps API

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I have created a single tenant application and assigned it as application user with System Administrator permissions to access one of my Dynamics environments, however I would also like to grant this application permissions to access PowerApps API (https://api.bap.microsoft.com), I couldn't find any informative article to answer what I'm trying to achieve here, and couldn't find a way to add the application user as admin for the PowerApps panel

To be specific I'm trying to perform the following API call using application user OAuth2 token
`https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/lifecycleOperations?api-version=2021-04-01`.
Response I get:

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "Forbidden",
> "message": "The service principal with id 'bd0000a6-2600-4e10-8d71-6d35e900000c' for application
> 5a00de00-79af-4400-b003-a3a136b94db9 does not have permission to
> access the path
> 'https://10.0.5.63:20062/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/lifecycleOperations?api-version=2021-04-01'
> in tenant e6000e48-bd54-413e-b005-df000000bd2c."
> } }

Azure AD application permissions didn't have anything for PowerApps API access (application user) to help me gain this access.

How can I provide access to my application user?

EDIT:
I obtained the access token using MSAL Python library, which the very same auth method works fine with my dynamics env URL..

```
AUTHORITY = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}'

SCOPES = ['https://api.bap.microsoft.com/.default']

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    authority=AUTHORITY,
    client_credential=CLIENT_SECRET,
)
token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=SCOPES)
```

Permissions(I didn't find anything for application permissions for PA):
[image]

Comment: Can you include how did you generate access token to call the API and the snip of the API permissions granted in the Azure AD application?

Comment: added both, auth method and permissions, I didn't find Application type permissions that might permit what I really want to do :/

Comment: If you are trying to access PowerApps then you have to grant API permissions like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/qQtHCcA.png), check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/programmability-authentication

Comment: But this is for delegated user, not application auth with client_credentials, am I wrong?

Comment: You can use client authentication check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/programmability-authentication#obtain-a-token-for-client-authentication but NOTE that: This can only be used after you have registered this client application ID with Microsoft Power Platform following either the related PowerShell or REST documentation.

Comment: Register the [**Application as an admin management application**](https://i.imgur.com/lG5EKu1.png) by using `https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/adminApplications/CLIENT_ID?api-version=2020-10-01`  and grant API permissions grant API permissions like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/qQtHCcA.png) and   generate the access token using client_credentials and now you will be able to access the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As I do not have any lifecycle Operations, I tried the sample query to access PowerApps API and got the same error as you:*

```json
https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments/myenv?api-version=2020-10-01&$select=properties/lifecycleOperationsEnforcement
```

[image]

> The service principal with id 'xxx' for application xxx does not have permission to access the path 'https://10.0.5.63:20062/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/lifecycleOperations?api-version=2021-04-01' in tenant xxx

The error usually occurs if the Azure AD application doesn't have sufficient permissions to perform the action.

**To resolve the error,** you have to register the client application ID with Microsoft Power Platform to access the PowerApps using Client Credential flow.

**Register an admin management application(Using PowerPlatform admin user):**

```json
PUT https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/adminApplications/ClientID?api-version=2020-10-01
```

[image]

Now I generated the **access token** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://api.bap.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Now when for sample **I tried to access the PowerApps API and its successful** like below:

```json
https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/scopes/admin/environments/myenv?api-version=2020-10-01&$select=properties/lifecycleOperationsEnforcement
```

[image]

You can generate the access token after registering the application as admin management application and pass **`https://api.bap.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.BusinessAppPlatform/lifecycleOperations?api-version=2021-04-01`** to access the PowerApps API.

**References:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerplatform-api-create-service-principal

[Programmability and Extensibility - Authentication - Power Platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/programmability-authentication)

Comment: Wonderful, works!

Comment: I didn't understand the part why do we need our app to have Delegated permissions for PowerApps service? if we are authenticating using client credentials, can u tell?
Because I was able to do it without the delegated permissions, I think we need them, unless we are authenticating with this application using user_impersonation, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes no need of PowerApps service permission you can call the API without it